# How to use an array in multiple functions when you don't know what the length will be at the start of your program

Tags: c, cs50

I have a project where I need to use an array within two different functions, but the length of it varies based on command line arguments, so I won't know what it is until later. How can I initialize the array globally, but then when I know the length later I can change the length. Here is the most simplified version of the problem I could make:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


char tile_numbers[1];
void print (void);

int main (void)
{
    int x = 7;
    char tile_numbers[x];
    tile_numbers[0] = 'h';
    tile_numbers[1] = 'e';
    tile_numbers[2] = 'l';
    tile_numbers[3] = 'l';
    tile_numbers[4] = 'o';
    tile_numbers[5] = '!';

    print();

}

void print (void)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        printf("char: %c", tile_numbers[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see how the length varies here. Pass the length as a parameter to the function which needs to know it.

Comment: This code does not make sense, nor does it correspond to the title. Learn C from a good textbook, not some obscure online courses/tutorials or - worst - youtube videos.

Comment: @Olaf deleted them.

Comment: The number of command line arguments can be known with `argc` as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: There is nothing passed to `main`.

Comment: The `tile_numbers` array that your `print` function sees is the global `tile_numbers` array of length 1. But your `print` function is printing 10 elements, going past the end of the array. That results in _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @Olaf So, OP need to change the `main` signature.

Comment: I was just trying to show the point, this isn't the actual code.

Comment: theoretically, if I want to use an array globally, but won't know the size till later, how do I do that?

Comment: Theoretically, the effective size must be determined before using the array. Use variable intended for size, or if you can use it, set a sentinel.

Comment: Also You can't create a dynamically sized array(E.g VLA) with file scope(as globally) on pure arrays. Use a pointer instead.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: He needs to clarify. As-is, it is not clear what he wants.

Comment: @Olaf What I wanted is the one that I starred as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of arrays, you can dynamically allocate memory using `malloc()`. Suppose at run time you have the size of the array stored in an `int` variable `n`. Then, you can allocate memory using

```
char *tile_numbers = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
```

Then, you can index the memory locations as before, as `tile_numbers[i]` for any `i` in the range `0` to `n-1`.

---

If you need it to declare it globally, separate the declaration and assignment. Globally, use

```
char *tile_numbers;
```

In the function where you get the size,

```
tile_numbers = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
```

In addition, if you need to resize the amount of memory, you can use `realloc()`,

```
tile_numbers = (char*)realloc(tile_numbers,new_size);
```

Comment: I think OP wants `tile_numbers` to be a global variable.

Comment: @IanAbbott It can be declared globally and allocated when needed? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: If it is declared globally, you can't call `malloc` in the initializer, so you'd need a separate assignment statement in the code. I mean as the statement is currently written, it would only work for a variable of automatic storage class. (I'm sure _you_ know that, but OP seems to be a beginner.)

Comment: If your Compiler tells you that you need that cast on Malloc, then you should start looking for a C compiler.

Comment: > char *tile_numbers;

This is what I was looking for, that's all I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use a global** - define the array in `main` (or wherever it is initially allocated), then pass it as an argument to the functions that need to use it:

```
void print( size_t size, const char *arr)
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    printf( "char: %c\n", arr[i] );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  // define tileNumbers here -- we'll get into details below

  print( arraySize, tileNumbers );
  return 0;
}
```

Do not get in the habit of using global (file scope) variables - it leads to code that's hard to maintain and extend.  *Sometimes* it's justified, but you don't know what those times are yet.  As a rule, functions should only share information through parameters or return values; they should not share global state.

Since you don't know how big `tileNumbers` needs to be until runtime, you can't allocate it as a fixed-size array and resize it later.  You'll need to defer the definition of the array until you know the size.

Prior to C99, your only option was to use dynamic memory (i.e., `malloc` or `calloc`):

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc declaration
...
size_t arraySize = getArraySize( );  // where getArraySize is a stand in for any code that sets arraySize

char *tileNumbers = malloc( sizeof *tileNumbers * arraySize );
if ( tileNumbers )
{
  // code to initialize tileNumbers goes here

  print( arraySize, tileNumbers );

  // deallocate memory when we're done with it
  free( tileNumbers );
}
```

Since C99, you can use what's called a *variable-length array* (VLA).  A VLA behaves *mostly* like a regular fixed-length array, but since its size isn't known until runtime, it can't be declared at file scope (can't use it as a global), can't be a member of a `struct` or `union` type, and can't have an initializer in its declaration.

```
size_t arraySize = getArraySize( );  // where getArraySize is a stand in for any code that sets arraySize;

char tileNumbers[arraySize];

// code to initialize tileNumbers goes here

print( arraySize, tileNumbers );
```

Either way, the prototype for `print` will stay the same.  In the first case, we're passing a pointer.  In the second case, we're passing an array expression, which *decays* to a pointer expression when evaluated.